# How to detect string initial in python?

Tags: python, string

For example I have a string:

```
"Hello My name is Ralph"
```

is there any way I could detect `H. M. n. i. R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do this with a regex, this would work:

```
re.findall(r'\b(\w)\w*\b',MY_STRING)
```

How this works:

`\b` is a word boundary. You can check for a word in regex by using `\bWord\b`, and it will return a match for `Word`

`(\w)` This is a group, matching a single letter. Since this is the only group, this is what is returned as the "match" by the regex

`\w*` This searches for additional letters in a row, of any length or no length. You didn't include any punctuation, but if you wanted the regex to not break on apostrophes you could change this to something like `[\w\']*` instead

Comment: Is there any link for this so that I can look further into it? thank you in advance sir

Answer (score 5):

try :

```
myText = "Hello My name is Ralph"
print [x[0] for x in myText.split()]
```